# Unity Xcode Build "Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue"

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, build

[XCode Error SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua3fT.jpg)

[Unity Build Settings SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKwyB.jpg)

We have not encountered such an error in our builds before, but at the , xcode has begun to give us such an error.

XCode Error Text : 
Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the "Unity-iPhone" target's entitlements.
Automatic signing can't add the application-identifier and keychain-access-groups entitlements to your provisioning profile. Switch to manual signing and resolve the issue by downloading a matching provisioning profile from the developer website. Alternatively, to continue using automatic signing, remove these entitlements from your entitlements file and their associated functionality from your code.
Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.CoffeeApp.CoffeeAppTest" doesn't include the application-identifier and keychain-access-groups entitlements.

I'd appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: Which plugin are you using to access the keychain?

Comment: I think use Vuforia

Comment: @Paulw11 Its better to post the duplicate question's URL in the comments.

Comment: @SachinVas, no.  It is a duplicate.  Variations of this question are all over SO today, as it seems Apple has a problem with free program memberships